# android third party app

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to install an unreleased third party android apk file into my device  from a windows pc or mac osx machine without having to install Android SDK and going the whole nine yards. Can it be done? Appreciate any help/pointers.

Comment: For future reference, this is probably better suited for the [Android Stack Exchange site](http://android.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Email the .apk to yourself and open the attachment on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to a File browser program such as "ASTRO" to locate the APK file and execute.  In additio, you will also need to enable 3rd party applications within the settings of the phone.  To enable 3rd party apps, just tap the HOME key then menu key, and select Settings.  Tap applications from the settings list and check the box labeled "Unknown Sources".  This will allow you to install apk files from "ASTRO" or any other file browsing program that you installed from the app store.  The installation will prform the same as it would from the app store.

Answer (score 2):

Easily. copy the apk to sdcard, then run some file manager installed on your phone(for example ASTRO) and launch the apk from it.

Comment: Bravo Vlado, nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use the "sideload wonder machine" to install apps in the manner of the sdk without installing the sdk.  On a phone without the 3rd party apps setting, only this mechanism is available.